# Concerns with glass slides vs glassless

Tags: film, slides, print-preservation, archive

When developing and storing color (or black and white for that matter) slide film, I've seen that you have two major types of slide mounts: glass and glassless.

From what I've read, glass is better for storage because if your slides get shuffled around then scratched you're ruined and glass will help prevent that.

On the other side, you have glassless which is significantly cheaper.

---

It sounds like for long term preservation glass would be preferred; however, glass isn't perfectly smooth. So will handling the slides, looking at them, and projecting them damage the slide in the long term?

Also, if the slides are just kept in binders and seldom viewed, how much of a difference will I see with just putting them in glassless slides, in a Print File slide sheet, and in an archive binder?

Is it going to matter that much with that setup compared to doing the same thing with glass slides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some useful info on this from Kodak here:
[Storage and Care of KODAK Photographic Materials](http://www.kodak.com/global/en/consumer/products/techInfo/e30/e30.pdf)

Quoting from this Kodak publication:
"Glass mounts do not have any significant effect on the useful life of slides except to help protect them from dirt and scratches. (Before you mount slides in glass mounts, be sure that the glass surfaces are clean.) Moisture may condense on the inside of glass mounts when you project them with high-wattage lamps. You can eliminate this problem by storing the slides with silica gel".

More important for archival storage than whether slide mounts include glass or not is to protect film from light, heat and humidity - which can be an easy or a difficult thing to achieve depending on local conditions.

Comment: Currently living in Louisiana, USA humidity is a big concern; however, everything I'm concerned with is from 2004 or sooner and most being from 2014. Thanks!